# Difference between iload with '_' and without

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jasmin

I hava a question about the iload instruction of jasmin.
Is it correct to do iload 1 or it has to be iload_1?
Or when is a number between 1 and 3 we have to use the '*' and the others we have to not use the '*'?

I m generating jasmin code.
First i tried every iload intruction with '*', but it didn't work. Then I tried every instruction without '*', and it also didn't work.

Comment: it is `iload_1` with underscore

Comment: but if it was 4 we would have to use without the '_'. For example iload 10

Comment: yes, 0-3 are shortcut commands, number is part of the name, not index argument

Comment: Of course, when you tried “iloud”, it didn’t work as the instruction is named “iload”. Any other issue with the syntax might be related to Jasmin, as there is no standard assembly syntax for Java. [The specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-6.html) provides names for the instructions, but without the intend to define a binding assembly language definition. So tools like Jasmin are likely to use the same names for the instructions as other tools, but use of space characters or separators may differ.

Answer (score 2):

The Java byte code contains a generic `iload` instruction that takes a value from 0 to 255 as argument (and therefore the encoding is 2 bytes).

For compacter byte code it contains 4 special instructions `iload_0` to `iload_3` that have a fixed argument (0 to 3) and are encoded in only one byte.

Similar patterns exist for several other byte code instructions.

The `iload` instructions are described in the JVM specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iload). On that page you will also find descriptions for all the other byte code instructions.

Comment: For completion: there’s also `wide iload n` where `n` can be up to 65535.